# Is there a name for the set of single-character prefixes of words in a regular language

Tags: terminology, regular-language, regular-expressions

This question concerns regular languages and regular expressions.

Suppose we have an alphabet $\Sigma$ and a language $\mathcal{L}$. For some algorithm, I am particularly concerned with the set of *first symbols* of all words in $\mathcal{L}$. So I was wondering whether there exists a name for such a set (defined below):

$$
A = \{ a \in \Sigma \mathrel{|} \exists w. aw \in \mathcal{L} \}
$$

Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I call it *the set of first letters of the words of $L$*.
See Example 5.2, page 54 in [these notes](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejep/PDF/MPRI/MPRI.pdf).